# How exactly dependency injection is implemented internally in Spring.net?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, spring, spring.net

I'm just curious to know about this.When i heard about Spring.net and tried some sample codes of DI i found it cool and eventually i was curious to know how it works and implemented internally? Even though have the src along with the framework i'm not yet good enough to find out where and how it is done.

Is this something to do with Reflection ? (A Dilbert quote here:- "A little knowledge can be too dangerous" :-) )

Comment: It's an open source project. If you want to know, look at the source. S
See sourceforge.net/projects/springnet/. Unless someone can post links to papers on the internals, I would think this should be closed, as it could only be answered by people who know the internals.

Comment: @John : I had mentioned in my question that src comes with the framework and im not yet good enough to find out how it's implemented. I was looking for general implementation logic here by someone who knows the internals, on which i can learn. Thanks.

Comment: @bintechie: that's why I said "Unless someone can post links to papers on the internals". Hopefully, someone can do that. They may have to post about the internals of the Java version, though.

Comment: @bintechie: you may also want to spend more time learning it, in depth. You'll understand the internals better if you understand the features they support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand how the basic injection mechanism works, take a look at [this simple, 15-LoC dependency injection container](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/10/20/Building-an-IoC-container-in-15-lines-of-code.aspx).

Of course, real containers like Spring.Net are vastly more sophisticated, but that's the general idea.

Comment: I remember reading that blog post. Great example of the concept at a high level.